# Load Parquet file into HDFS table-Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hdfs

I am trying to load a file and write it to my HDFS path as a parquet file. However whenever I run the code below, no values are inserted.

Below is my code:

```
#Import Key functions
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("Spark_TESTT").config("spark.config.option","yarn-client").getOrCreate()

#Call Database
spark.sql("USE db1")


#Create(or load) Table #1
spark.sql("create  external table if not exists mx_test ( c0 string, c1 string, c2 string) COMMENT 'Sample Test' stored as parquet location 'hdfs://hadoop_data/path/mx_test'")


df = spark.read.load("/user/files/sample*.txt", format="text" ,inferSchema="false", header="false", sep=",")
df.write.save('hdfs://hadoop_data/path/mx_test/new.parquet", format="parquet")
```

When I do a selct * from statement it shows the following:

[image]

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to load data into **`hdfs://hadoop_data/path/mx_test/`** this directory `(as table pointed to this directory)`, then check you are able to see data in Hive table.

```
df.write.save('hdfs://hadoop_data/path/mx_test/', format="parquet")
```

### ***`UPDATE:`***

Please check the **column names** in your **`parquet file vs hive table`** column names.

if column names are not same then **`hive parquet table displays null`** values for them.

> ### `How to check column names, types in parquet file?`

**`Use parquet-tools to check the schema for the parquet file:`**

```
bash$ parquet-tools meta hdfs://<namenode_address:8020><hdfs_path_to_parquet_file>
```

**(or)**

**`Copy parquet file to local the check the schema:`**

```
bash$ parquet-tools meta <local_path_to_parquet_file>
```

Now create `hive table schema` matching with the parquet file, then check are you able to get the data instead of `NULL`.

Comment: @James Davinport, Please check the Updated answer addressing null's in hive table.